# Describing multivariable functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, plane-curves

So I am presented with the following question:

Describe and sketch the largest region in the $xy$-plane that corresponds to the domain of the function:
$$g(x,y) = \sqrt{4 - x^2 - y^2} \ln(x-y).$$

Now to be I can find different restrictions like $4 - x^2 - y^2 \geq 0$... but I'm honestly not even sure where to begin this question! Any help?

Comment: @Marvis: this is not always the right thing to do! Sometimes your answers just aren't satisfactory. I'd phrase it as "we'd like it if you upvoted answers you found helpful, and accepted ones which answered your question; the FAQ has instructions on [how and when to upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) and accepting is covered in the FAQ for [how to ask questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask)"

Comment: @Marvis: you don't need to remove it; after I posted that comment I went to go look for the meta advice on this and I couldn't find it, so maybe you're right. I just think we should phrase it as a "hey, there's this thing you can do" rather than a command (although I appreciate you used the word "kindly").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you need two things:
$$ 4 - x^2 - y^2 \geq 0 $$
to get make the square root work, and also
$$ x-y > 0 $$
to make the logarithm work.

You will be graphing two regions in the $xy$-plane, and your answer will be the area which is in both regions.

A good technique for graphing a region given by an inequality is to first replace the inequality by an equality.  For the first region this means
$$ 4 - x^2 - y^2 = 0$$
$$ 4 = x^2 + y^2 $$
Therefore, we're talking about the circle of radius two centered at the origin.  The next question to answer: do we want the inside or outside of that circle?  To determine that, we use a test point: pick any point not on the circle and plug it into the inequality.  I'll choose $(x,y) = (5,0)$.  Note that this point is on the outside of the circle.
$$ 4 - x^2 - y^2 \geq 0 $$
$$ 4 - 5^2 - 0^2 \geq 0 $$
That's clearly false, so we do not want the outside of the circle.  Our region is the inside of the circle.  Shade that lightly on your drawing.

Now, do the line by the same algorithm.

Comment: It is not $x-y\ge0$.  It is $x-y\gt0$, because $\log(0)$ is undefined.

Comment: Very clear, thanks!

Comment: @Salmon: thanks; edited.

Answer (score 1):

When is $g(x,y)$ defined and takes a real value?  Well, the square root has to be of a positive number, so $x^2+y^2\le4$.  Also, when you are taking $\log(x-y)$, for the logarithm to be defined, $x-y$ must be greater than $0$.  Thus, the domain of $g(x,y)$ consists of all points $(x,y)$ such that

(1) $x^2+y^2\le4$ and

(2) $y<x$

Sketch (1) and (2) on an $xy$ plane.  (1) is a filled-in circle with radius $2$ centered around the origin (all points on the boundary are points in the domain).  (2) is all points strictly below the line $y=x$ (all points on the boundary are *not* points in the domain).  For $g(x,y)$ to be defined, both (1) and (2) must be satisfied, so we must take the intersection of these two figures.

Comment: Great, I will do it out soon and check back if I get issues with my math... thanks!

Comment: Just FYI, I made an edit, and I corrected an error.  Before, I said all points above the line, but it should of said all points below the line $y=x$.  Sorry for the inconvenience.